# Can't change sqlnet.ora runtime?

Tags: oracle, kerberos, oracle-call-interface

I am trying to setup Kerberos authentication for my Oracle database and I have a situation where I need to maintain different versions of sqlnet.ora for each kerberos user connection. My application is using OCI driver (a single unix process does more than one user connection to the same Oracle database). And I am not able switch sqlnet.ora between user connections using setenv(TNS_ADMIN) call programmatically. I am assuming once the contents of sqlnet.ora gets loaded to process, it remains unchanged for the rest of its life.

Is my case a practical one, has anyone encountered?

When it comes to kerberos, I am not sure why Oracle client restricts the sqlnet.ora to one principal kerberos user. Maybe Oracle does not have a clean support for kerberos as I dont see OCI API's?

Thanks
Srivatsan

Comment: Or can I just merge all the key tab files into one and maintain one version of sqlnet.ora? How will my connection string change from providing only tns_alias name? Should I also provide username when I merge all the keytab files? Please help.

Comment: Please go to dba.stackexchange.com